# Restful Response Showing \n Instead of New Line

Tags: spring, rest, text, response

I am trying to generate a TEXT/PLAIN response for my Spring application.

When I am debugging the code, I see the string nicely formatted:

```
LINE1
LINE2
...
```

But when I see the response in Postman I see that the output is all messed up like

```
LINE1\nLIINE2\n....
```

I am not sure if the set up the controller properly or not!

Here is my Controller class:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ConfigGeneratorController {

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    Logger logger = null;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/configGenerator", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE})

    public ConfigGenerator configGenerator(@RequestBody String xml) {

        logger = Logger.getLogger(ConfigGeneratorController.class.getName());

        .
        .
        .
        bunch of code
        .
        .
        .

        return new ConfigGenerator(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(actionMonitor.getGeneratedConfig().replaceAll("^\t+", "")));
    }

}
```

actionMonitor.getGeneratedConfig() is the method that returns the string.

Comment: I think the issue is about HTML. Is this [answer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html) helpful to you ?

Comment: @MontassarElBéhi Apologies I think posted the incorrect code above. I edited it, the produces part I actually was using TEXT/PLAIN, but I posted TEXT/HTML. But according to that method:
HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(actionMonitor.getGeneratedConfig().replaceAll("^\t+", ""))
Is this the right way to use it?
If it is, I tried it, but it doesn't work.